How to delete an entire index?
I created a lot of index entries, but, finally, I don't need an index. I'd like to remove my index without deleting every index entry. Is it possible to do that? This is my MWE:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

This is an index entry\index{Socrate}.


\printindex

\end{document}


If you remove \makeindex, then \index becomes a no-op. You should also remove \printindex, of course.
No need to remove \index commands in the typescript.
Complete recipe:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%\usepackage{imakeidx}

%\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is an index entry\index{Socrate}.

%\printindex

\end{document}


Thanks! The problem is that I use RStudio and a YAML to knit my file and that I can't — or don't know how — comment out my preamble.

@domi Sorry, you have to solve the problem yourself.

@domi well, if you remove \printindex from the body, it won't be printed.
